# Simple audio forewarding scheme

Tags: audio, forwarding, xforwarding

```
laptop(1) - wifi router(2) - wifi enabled PC(3) - speakers(4)
```

(1) is a portable laptop, running some graphical interface. It has ssh access to (3) set up.

(3) is an old machine, and thus running `debian` without a graphical environment. It's purpose is to output analog audio to the amplifier and is thus stationary.

I would like to have a virtual audio device on (1), which forwards any sound (youtube, local audio files, games sounds - everything) to (3). Sould I use some form of `X`, `jack`, `pulse` or something even simpler?

(1) is a `debian` with `openbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Pulseaudio has several ways to do it, for example with `module-rtp-send` and `module-rtp-receive`, for details see [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index7h2).

Use an additional `module-null-sink` if you want to have a "network sink" in your laptop, so you can switch between the remote speakers and other sinks in the usual way.

This also scales to multiple receiving PCs via multicast.